# Just Purchased First Mac & Have Some Software Questions

Tags: macos

I have just purchased my new mac, which is the 27inch imac with 3.4ghz quad processor, 8gb of ram, 1tb hard drive and a AMD Radeon HD 6970M 1GB GDDR5 graphics card.

I was told this is the best machine, apart from the ram not being 16gb but I thought it was not needed, but I may be wrong.

Anyway I was wondering what software will compensate for what I already have on the pc.

I am a web designer and coder.

Also do you know if adobe allow you to use pc license on mac? the reason I ask is I have just purchase creative suite cs6 on pc and it has 3pc license. I have used it on just 1 machine, will it allow me to use it on mac?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, the licenses are, in fact, OS specific.  I ran across this problem recently (at home, I use a Mac, at work I use a PC) and couldn't get a proper install working.  Alternatives?  Well, it's not quite as shiny, but Gimp has gotten quite good recently.  For any other software check out [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/).  It's a pretty spiffy site for finding software not available on your platform (or in your price range).

EDIT:

NEARLY FORGOT MY FAVORITE PIECE OF MAC SOFTWARE: [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/)!  If you like your code editors slim, TextWrangler is for you.  None of that tag closing crap, VERY solid built-in FTP, fully customizable code-coloring, low profile interface.

Answer (score 0):

If adobe is available for mac i`m almost sure the license will count for the mac to. Why dont just try it? OR take a look at http://www.adobe.com/nl/support/

Comment: i have had a look on adobe and i can not see that its allowed nor dis allowed. I do not get the mac until Friday when it gets delivered, i am asking a couple of questions on here so i can get all relevant software so it will not take me long to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I guess not. But you can try to run Windows in Parallels/VmWare/VirtualBox on MAC and launch Adobe inside.